# How to manage data annotations with two forms on page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, data-annotations

For example i have two forms on one page and model is following

**Model**

```
 public class PageVM
    {

        public PageVM()
        {
        }

        [Required]
        public int Form1_RecordId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Form1_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Form1_Surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Form2_RecordId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Form2_Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Form2_SizeOfShoes { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Page", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form1_RecordId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form1_RecordId)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form1_Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form1_Name)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form1_Surname)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form1_Surname)

    <input type="submit" name="submitForm1" value="submit Form1" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Page", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form2_RecordId)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form2_RecordId)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form2_Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form2_Name)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Form1_SizeOfShoes)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Form1_SizeOfShoes)

    <input type="submit" name="submitForm2" value="submit Form2" />
}
```

but when I submit Form1 I got error that Form2 required inputs are not set and otherwise.. what is best practice for this scenario ?

Comment: You need to show you view. (why does you view have 2 forms - you can only submit one?)

Comment: You can submit Form1 or Form2 it depends on user choice, I will add a view to the question

Comment: It seems that you are dividing your model in two different forms. In such cases, the error you are getting is very obvious because some of the mandatory fields of model will always be blank in one or the other form during submit. You should either break your model into two. Or keep all fields to optional, and then put the Javascript and/or server-side validations

Comment: You view makes no sense. What are you trying to achieve with this? (you could just have 2 properties in you model and one form (but with 2 submit buttons if you need some kind of distinction)

Comment: Stephen: It is an example, I edited question to be more clear. I will try Parent Model pattern as Nirman suggested.